# changing parent environment of closure in R (a good idea)?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I haven't seen much (popular) literature about the manipulation of function environments / the use of `<<-` in R (aside from in [adv-r](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)). In particular, what are the taboos of R with respect to these things. To make this a concrete question, consider the following functions:

```
appendOne <- function(env=parent.frame()) {
   tmp <- function(.x) {
     eval(substitute(.x <<- c(.x, "1")))
   }
   parent.env(environment(tmp)) <- env
   return(tmp)
}

g <- function() {
   .y <- 4
   appendOne()(.y)
   .y 
}
```

The point of appendOne is pretty obvious. Now the questions are (and I understand that this is partly subjective):

1. What about this strategy of making functions solely for their side-effects is dangerous in R?
2. Is this kind of programming pattern "taboo" in R? I don't see much of the `eval`-`substitute` pattern aside from at the very highest levels. Is this because its hard to explain to beginners, or because it isn't encouraged?

Comment: The preference for functions without side effects is a hallmark of [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) in general. As the first paragraph of that linked Wikipedia page explains, "Eliminating side effects, i.e. changes in state that do not depend on the function inputs, can make it much easier to understand and predict the behavior of a program, which is one of the key motivations for the development of functional programming."

Comment: Also, FWIW, a function call  to `g()` (or for that matter to `appendOne()`) freezes my R session.

Comment: He is trying to access `g` from inside `appendOne` before it is defined. This is going to lead to weird behavior.

Comment: Woops! That was a typo... It's been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming heavily encourages the construction of functions with minimal side effects. The reason for this is that if a function has zero side effects, it is possible to give a full proof of the integrity of its behavior -- it will not modify anything outside of its own local environment.

However, there may be good reason to use the `eval(substitute(...))` pattern to "reach into" the calling environment--namely, for optimization purposes, and non-standard evaluation that *significantly* improves the experience of the user.

For example, in one of my packages, I [perform a very complicated evaluation in the calling environment](https://github.com/robertzk/mungebitsTransformations/blob/master/R/column_transformation.r), being very careful to not define any incidental local variables, because I greatly cared about optimization and did not want to descend into C.

For example, if you pass a dataframe into a function, make a modification on one column of that dataframe, and then return it, R will copy the entire dataframe. You can wrap it in an environment containing just that dataframe, but that also makes things harder to understand. Using non-standard evaluation can improve performance if you know that the user is aware of the side effects of the underlying function:

`(function(df) eval.parent(substitute(df[[1]] <- 2 * df[[1]])))(iris)`